# Bash script to run query on 28 cores

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to have an outfile query run a single process per value in an array to speed up the process of exporting data from mysql, id like to run the script on multiple cores. My bash script is:

```
dbquery=$(mysql -u user -p -e "SELECT distinct(ticker) FROM db.table")
array=( $( for i in $dbquery ; do echo $i ; done ) )
csv ()
{
dbquery=$(mysql -u user --password=password -e "SELECT * FROM db2.table2 WHERE symbol = '$i' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/$i.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'")
}

set -m

for i in 'seq 28'; do    #trying to run on 28 cores
  for j in ${array[@]}; do
    csv $j &
  done
  sleep 5 &
done

while [ 1 ]; 
do
  fg 2> /dev/null; [ $? == 1 ] && break;
done
```

Now I ran this and it is not exporting files as i wished it too and i cannot figure out how to kill the processes. Could you help me understand how to fix this so that it will run the outfile query per ticker? Also how do I kill the current script that is running without killing other scripts and programs that are running?

Comment: do a `man xargs`. It might make things easier. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xargs to automatically handle job scheduling:

```
dbquery=$(mysql -u user -p -e "SELECT distinct(ticker) FROM db.table")
array=( $( for i in $dbquery ; do echo $i ; done ) )
csv ()
{
dbquery=$(mysql -u user --password=password -e "SELECT * FROM db2.table2 WHERE symbol = '$i' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/$i.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'")
}

export -f csv
echo "${array[@]}" | xargs -P 28 -n 1 bash -c 'csv "$1"' --
```

The problem with your approach is that because the loops are nested, you start all processes 28 times each, rather than running them once and 28 at a time.

Answer (score 1):

`wait` will wait until all the child processes are done.

```
for i in 'seq 28'; do    #trying to run on 28 cores
  for j in ${array[@]}; do
    csv $j &
  done
done    
wait
```

Comment: I reset it to run on 15 cores, however it seems to be running on all cores. Do you know any reason for why this is happening? And thank you for the response.